# groupby: opitimizing code for multiple operations in single line

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have three lines need to convert in one line how can I do this with pandas and python ..

```
ml= 1000

1.line: agg_2 = main_df.groupby(['id_1','id_2'])['value'].agg(['min','max'])

2.line: tot = agg_2['max'].sub(agg_2['min']).shift(1)

3.line: main_df['hos_eve'] = (145 - (main_df.groupby(['id_1','id_2'])['vio_eve'].sum()* ml)/ tot)

main_df.shape: (11065065, 14)
main_df.groupby(['id_1','id_2'])['vio_eve'].sum().shape: (2013,)
agg_2['max'].sub(agg_2['min']).shift(1).shape: (2013,)
```

can I optimize first line and put in the divide section of third line

other wise showing error. or someone can tell me why this is error ?
because of attaching output of 3rd line to the main_df which has different shape?
if it is **true** then how can append the result to the main_df.

the error is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the multiple .groupby calls you can refactor the common expression out to an intermediary variable.

The group_by is only performed once and you help keep the code readable.

```py
main_gb = main_df.groupby(['id_1','id_2'])
agg_2   = main_gb['value'].agg(['min','max'])
tot     = agg_2['max'].sub(agg_2['min']).shift(1)
main_df['hos_eve'] = (145 - (main_gb['vio_eve'].sum()* ml)/ tot)
```

Comment: my concerned is about to reduce first two lines into one single line..  if is passing two times groupby then not an issue for me.

Comment: Do you have timing statistics illustrating the poor performance?

Comment: No stastistics which shows the illustrating the poor performance.
just want to optimize the code that's it or I can see to reduce the number of lines..